# Picasso in ViewPager causing GC

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-viewpager, picasso

I am trying to change viewpager page using a timer every 5seconds, everything works fine but I am noticing a GC pause every time when the viewpager page changes.

Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance.

> Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 143(8KB) AllocSpace
>   objects, 4(41MB) LOS objects, 19% free, 65MB/81MB, paused 1.386ms
>   total 117.193ms

```
//Calling every 5 seconds
viewPager.setCurrentItem(nextPage, true)
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private final TypedArray mResources;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, TypedArray resids) {
        this.mResources = resids;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Context context = imageView.getContext();

        //360x540
        int currentapiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (context != null && currentapiVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(mResources.getResourceId(position, 0))
                    .fit()
                    .into(imageView);
        } else if (context != null) {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(mResources.getResourceId(position, 0))
                    .resize(360, 540)
                    .into(imageView);
        }


        imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                setas_wall_dialog(v.getContext(), mResources.getResourceId(position, 0));
                return false;
            }
        });

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

I tried removing `.fit()` but still the same problem.

Allocation Tracker:
[image: Screenshot of my Allocation Tracker]

Comment: i am doing same thing, but nothing GC related in logcat

Comment: I don't see any problems in your question.